# Batch File- Command - Dynamic input for renaming folders

Tags: batch-file, input

- I am looking to rename a folder to just have the current date, or heck even .old
- Dynamic folder renaming

I wan to ask for a user input once, have it find the folder, then rename it once it is found. No matter what I do I get a syntax error

```
@ECHO off
cls

set /P FOLDER="What the Folder Name: "
rename "%userprofile%\Downloads\"%FOLDER%"" "%userprofile%\Downloads\"%FOLDER%" - %date:/=-%"
pause
cls
goto start
```

Output:

```
What the Folder Name: folder
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: `ren` or `rename` does not want the path as part of the second parameter. `ren "%userprofile%\Downloads\%FOLDER%" "%FOLDER% - %date:/=-%"` will work just fine.. Additionally, you do not need the funny quoting, which by the way you missed one `:)`

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO!!! HOURS BEING STUCK AND BAM YOU SWOOP IN AND SAVE THE DAY!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `ren /?` or `rename /?` states:

```
RENAME [drive:][path]filename1 filename2.
REN [drive:][path]filename1 filename2.
```

In other words, i only expects the new name as the second parameter. This will fail with syntax error:

```
ren "D:\My Folders\Old name" "D:\My Folders\New name"
```

Where this will perform the rename:

```
ren D:\My Folders\Old name" "New Name"
```

Additionally, you do not need the funny quoting. You simply need to quote the entire string once, to ensure `cmd` does not see the whitespace as command/parameter separators. So this code should do what you want:

```
@echo off & cls
set /p "FOLDER=What the Folder Name: "
rename "%userprofile%\Downloads\%FOLDER%" "%FOLDER%" - %date:/=-%"
pause
cls
goto start
```

All this being said, you mention dynamic. Nothing is dynamic here. This is all static requests to a user and hoping the answer with a valid result. So you could really make this more dynamic, but only if I have more detail on your requirements can I help.